# Error CS1061 MainWindow no contiene una definición para textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente código en el main:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Clases;
    using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

    namespace CasoOnbreakWPF
 {

   public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
   {
    ClienteCollection misClientes = new ClienteCollection();   

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Tile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        flyRegistrarU.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void btnRegistrarCliente_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente Clie = new Cliente();
        Clie.Rut = txtRut.Text;

        misClientes.Add(Clie);

        flyRegistrarU.IsOpen = false;

       }
     }
   }
```

A la hora de iniciar el programa me sale que el main con contiene una definición para TextBox_TextChanged Esto no me había pasado nunca y he programado en WPF antes, ahora le agregue el tema de mahapMetro, será por eso? la verdad no eh podido solucionarlo de ninguna manera ni creando una clase ni nada. busque por google alguna directivas pero nada que me sirviera o por lo menos las que vi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu textbox le asignaste un evento como te dice ahi. Luego borraste el evento del codebehind y en la vista te rompe. fijate en las propiedades del boton, ubica ese evento y borralo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente habrás creado un textbox, le habrás dado alguna propiedad y luego lo has cambiado de nombre. En cualquier caso debes ir al archivo `designer.cs` de tu formulario, buscar lo relativo a este textbox y eliminar las líneas que no sean coherentes.

En [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/design-time-errors-in-the-windows-forms-designer), tienes la información de este tipo de errores y de otros correspondientes a tiempo de diseño.

Comment: Muchas gracias man me sirvio mucho soy nuevo en esto y me ayudaste bastante. :)